# Twilio: How to get Call record for this month on a specific phone number in a subaccount

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I have been trying to find an API call that would allow me to get All call records that are made to one of the phone numbers attached to a subaccount. Each subaccount is for a department and each phone number attached to a subaccount is linked to a specific business case. We need to show analytics to users (heading the department) to show the phone numbers and their individual usage. Can this be done using Twilio API's? We need this functionality badly and any help from you would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

To access the subaccount data you can either use the master account credentials or the subaccount credentials to authenticate with the Twilio REST API.

If you use the master account credentials you'll need to make a [request to the Accounts resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts#listing-subaccounts-example-1) to get an instance of the specific subaccount you want to access.

To get the list of calls to to a specific phone number of the subaccount, you can us a list filter, which in PHP means providing an array to the Calls resource:

https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/rest/calls.html#listing-calls

There are a number of parameters that you can using to filter the results:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters

Hope that helps.